# Joomla 1.5: How to link a file in same directory

Tags: joomla1.5

In joomla 1.5 component, in the tmpl folder i want an image to be included in the default.php, please help me how can i add this as by default joomla look into the root directory?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following 2 pages:

- http://api.joomla.org/1.5/Joomla-Framework/Environment/JURI.html#base,
- http://docs.joomla.org/JURI/base

which shows recommended way for adding paths in joomla.
After that class just add the path to your image.